# SQL Convert Varchar to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have a query that grabs a yyyy-MM-dd format from a large storage field by substringing, so the value is automatically a varchar. An example of the entire record's contents is below:

```
EmployeeName$Test User
Email$test@test.com
ADUsername$tuser
TermDate$2023-07-13
EmployeeNumber$12345
Department$Tech
```

The following SQL query works and returns all data correctly, where TermDateString is never null and appears to be always formatted correctly:

```
with cte as (
    select i.IncidentNumber,
    case when charindex('TermDate$',i.symptom) = 0 or charindex('EmployeeNumber$',i.symptom) = 0 then null else
    substring(symptom,charindex('TermDate$',i.symptom) + 9,(charindex('EmployeeNumber$',i.symptom) - 2) - (charindex('TermDate$',i.symptom) + 9)) 
    end as 'TermDateString'
    from Incident i
    inner join task t on t.parentlink_recid = i.recid
    where i.subject like '%term in proc%'
    and i.status not in ('closed','cancelled','resolved')
    and i.symptom like '%EmployeeName%'
    and t.subject = 'Open WFH Equipment Return Request'
    and t.status not in ('closed','cancelled')
    --and i.incidentnumber = '5305093'
)
select *
--,convert(date,TermDateString,23) 'TermDate'
--,cast(TermDateString as date) 'TermDate'
from cte
--where convert(date,TermDateString,23) > DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE())
order by incidentnumber desc
```

[image: Results]

However, I need to only get tickets where TermDateString is within a certain time frame. When converting the varchar to a date or datetime, by uncommenting `--,convert(date,TermDateString,23) 'TermDate'`, it always throws this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I believe that it is not related to a specific record's data, as it is never null and I checked there are no leading/trailing white spaces. Additionally, I manually tested multiple records by uncommenting `--and i.incidentnumber = '5305093'`, which is the top result, as well as the 2nd result. Individually, both of those worked. However when doing a `Select top 2 i.incidentnumber` with `--and i.incidentnumber = 'xxxx'` still commented out, it throws the same error, meaning it only throws an error when it is trying to handle multiple records. I have also tried using CAST instead of CONVERT, but with the exact same results.

Does anybody know of a way to get this working?

Comment: `grabs a yyyy-MM-dd format from a large storage field by substringing` that's a huge bug. Fix the bug instead of trying to cover it up. If you really want to query some data, it needs to be a separate field. You can use JSON or XML values to store a "bag" of rarely queried data and still be able to easily extract parts of it with XML or JSON functions

Comment: I 100% agree. Unfortunately I do not own the database, so I can only work with what I have

Comment: You can convert the value into JSON and use JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY to extract the parts you want. Replace `$` with `":"`, newlines with `","` and surround the string with `{"` and `"}`. This won't be any slower than the existing method but it will you'll be able to write a single `JSON_VALUE(...)` to get the date, eg `cast(JSON_VALUE(json_str,'$.TermDate') as date)`. The date type recognizes the ISO8601 format

Answer (score 0):

If the data can't be fixed, you can convert it to JSON by replacing `$` with `":"`,  `\r\n` with `":" and surround the result with` {"`and`}"`:

```
declare @field nvarchar(3000)='EmployeeName$Test User
Email$test@test.com
ADUsername$tuser
TermDate$2023-07-13
EmployeeNumber$12345
Department$Tech'

declare @as_json varchar(3000)='{"' + replace(replace(@field,'$','":"'),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'","') + '"}'
```

The field is converted to JSON with this expression:

```
'{"' + replace(replace(@field,'$','":"'),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'","') + '"}'
```

You can extract the `TermDate` with a single call to `JSON_VALUE` and cast it directly to a `date`.

```
select cast(JSON_VALUE(@as_json,'$.TermDate') as date)
```

Or, as a single expression:

```
select cast(JSON_VALUE('{"' + replace(replace(@field,'$','":"'),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'","') + '"}','$.TermDate') as date)
```

If you have to do this frequently, you can even use the complete expression to create a computed column and even index it.

You can create a function to convert that format to JSON, to make it easier to write expressions:

```
create function To_Json(@field nvarchar(4000))
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
BEGIN
    return '{"' + replace(replace(@field,'$','":"'),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'","') + '"}'
END
```

And use it :

```
select cast(JSON_VALUE(dbo.To_Json(@field),'$.TermDate') as date)
```

You could also create a function that retrieves the path you want directly:

```
create function Get_By_Path(@field nvarchar(4000),@path nvarchar(200))
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
BEGIN
    declare @json nvarchar(4000)= '{"' + replace(replace(@field,'$','":"'),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'","') + '"}'
    return JSON_VALUE(@json,@path)
END
```

And use it in a query:

```
select cast(dbo.get_by_path(@field,'$.TermDate') as date)
```